# Storing a javascript promise

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I'm pretty new to Node and have decided to convert one of my code bases to async/await. Converting the callbacks to Async/await has been relatively an easy process but I have run into a problem where I store the callback in a queue.

```
    this.on("request", (requestString, response) => {
        // Check if there are no available workers
        if (this.freeWorkers.length === 0) {
            logger.info("Workers are busy please wait...");
            this.queue.push([requestString, response]);
        } else {
            const worker = this.freeWorkers.pop();
            /* Run the worker and send back the response */
            worker.run(requestString, response, data => {
                response(data); 
            });
        }
    });
```

The problem I am having is that I don't want to break from async/await by using new Promise(resolve, reject) if I don't have to. The above version works well because another event "return" will complete the stored callback when there is a request in this.queue. The async version looks like this:

```
async request (requestString) {
    if (this.freeWorkers.length === 0) {
        logger.info("Workers are busy please wait...");
        this.queue.push([requestString, /* How do I store the promise here? */]);
    } else {
        logger.info("sending request...");
        const worker = this.freeWorkers.pop();

        /* Run the worker and send back the response */
        return await worker.run(requestString);
    }
}
```

The question being how from inside an async/await function do I store the promise in this.queue()?

**Edit:** Adding in some additional details as requested to hopefully clear up some confusion.

The "API" if you could call it that is from an ancient IBM software from 1982 that my company uses internally. `this.on("request"` is emitted from another class in my API. If your curious this is what the worker currently looks like:

```
/**
 * Class Worker is a simple class with only a constructor and 1 run method
 * sends a plain TCP request
 * Uses a callback response and closes the connection
 * */
class Worker {
/**
 * Sets variables that it will use in the future
 *
 * @param {number} port
 * @param {TracsRequest} eventEmitter
 * */
constructor(port, eventEmitter) {
    this.host = /* redacted */;
    this.port = port;
    this.emitter = eventEmitter;
    this.lastRequest = null;
    this.lastResponse = null;
}

/**
 * Takes in a formatted request string and opens a TCP Port to parse the request
 *
 * @param requestString
 * @param response
 */
async run(requestString) {
    this.lastRequest = requestString;
    this.lastResponse = response;
    const socket = new net.Socket();
    let tempBuffer = null;
    const client = socket.connect(
        this.port,
        this.host,
        () => {
            client.write(requestString);
        }
    );


    let socketPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        /**************************
         * SOCKET EVENT LISTENERS *
         **************************/
        // store the incoming data
        client.on("data", data => {
            tempBuffer += data;
        });

        // client has finished respond with the data
        client.on("end", () => {
            logger.info("the client has finished");

            this.emitter.emit("return", this);
            client.destroy();

            tempBuffer = tempBuffer.substring(4);
            resolve(tempBuffer);
        });

        // Client has responded with an error send the worker back to the Request class
        client.on("error", error => {
            logger.error(`OHH snap he's dead Jim:${error}`);
            reject(error);
        });
    });

    return await socketPromise;
}
```

}`

Comment: are you sure it's a promise, because I can see in your code is you had used `async` and not having `await` inside, which is make it useless.

Comment: Hello MrTaco. Please write a question explicitly and make it as clear as you can, assuming it must be useful to a person who comes across this problem for the first time.

Comment: Hi guys, I made the question more explicit and corrected the bottom example to actually be an async function. Sorry about the errors there first time reaching out for help!

Comment: Can you please provide the library / documentation that uses `this.on("request"` and `worker.run`? I see you modified the code (with fewer parameters) but It's hard to understand why without Api references

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing some more digging I was able to come up with a working async example. This example does use `new Promise()` which I believe is the best way to achieve what I had asked since async/await does not have a resolve function that I can store into an array.

```
async request (requestString) {
    let data = false;
    try {
        if (this.freeWorkers.length === 0) {
            logger.info("Workers are busy please wait...");
            let queuePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.queue.push([requestString, resolve, reject]);
            });

            /* await for the queue to run this request */
            data = await queuePromise;
        } else {
            logger.info("sending request...");
            const worker = this.freeWorkers.pop();

            /* Run the worker and send back the response */
            data = await worker.run(requestString);
        }   
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error("Something went wrong in request");
        throw error;
    }

    return data;
}
```

Thanks to the other answer on this to lead me in the right direction! I also formatted the function with try/catch so errors aren't unhandled.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't shown us the code that re-adds workers to the pool and/or pulls from the work queue, which I'll call `replenish`. Whatever is happening there is going to need to either call a function (`response`) or complete a promise (presumably by calling `resolve` saved from a `new Promise` constructor). After all, even if you could store a Promise, the idea is that you can't *resolve* it externally with only a reference to the Promise—you really do need to keep a reference to `resolve` to change the Promise's status.

I'd call `new Promise()` in `request`, save the `resolve` function, and add that to the queue. That means that your worker-replacer and queue-inspector function `replenish` doesn't need to deal with Promises, it just needs to deal with calling the function when it's done with the work.